# Magmi not importing pricing format correctly

Tags: magento-1.8, magmi

pricing formats are working correctly except when a price is over 1000.00
for example we have a product that is 1075.00 and it is showing up as $1.75

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party module support.